# Get id from database using a Name as parameter

Tags: java, database, android-studio

I would like to ask a "basic" question about retrieving data from a database. I have a database with three columns (ID, BeerName, Time). I would like to get the ID of a beer that matches a name

I have tried to use a method call "getId" but it doesn't work (or maybe I did not recall it properly).

this is my database

```
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ProvaBeers.db";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String TABLE_BEERS = "Beers";
static final String COL0 = "beer_id";
static final String COL1 = "beer_name";
static final String COL2 = "time";
```

this is supposed to be the method I use to get the ID. 
beername is the name I want to find in the database and the its ID is what I am trying to find

```
public Integer getId(String beername){

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT beer_id FROM "+TABLE_BEERS+" WHERE "+COL1+" = "+ beername, null);
    Integer id_ = cur.getInt(0);
    return id_;
}
```

What I would like my app to do is:

I use the name of the beer in the database to get its ID in the database. I know generally it is the opposite but this is what I need. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably an Exception is being thrown.  The `beerName` value should be wrapped in single quotes

Comment: @ScaryWombat is correct, this will fail as you are missing quotes. But also if this is going to end up public then make sure its not subject to sql injection, which it would be if beername is coming off a user-entered field on a web page, for example.